# Angular $filter is not working in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am formatting the existing date using `Angular.js` but its only working in chrome. I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.timestamp=2016-12-16 07:58:30 AM 
$scope.orginalTime= $filter('date')(new Date($scope.timestamp.replace("-","/")),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a');
```

Here i am formatting the date time but its only working in chrome. I need this should work in all browser including `firefox,safari+MAC`.

Comment: Did you verify that the date string from `$scope.timestamp.replace(…)` is properly parsed by `Date`, cf. [this disclaimer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Description)? Protip: The provided format is neither RFC2822 nor ISO-8601 syntax so I think you're relying on Chrome being more forgiving in its parsing. Consider splitting the date into parts or format to a valid format.

Comment: I would suggest you to format the date in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ format. & then you can directly use something like this <$ timestamp | date:"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" $>. This is working in all the browsers as it is angularjs's date filter

Comment: You could take a look at the [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) library to parse your timestamp into a regular Date object, that you can afterwards format the way you want with `$filter`.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to manually parse strings as results are inconsistent across browsers. You do something like this

```
function parseDate(timestamp){

   raw = timestamp.split(" ");
   date = raw[0].split("-");
   time = raw[1].split(":");
   month = parseInt(date[1]-1);
   hour = raw[2] == "AM" ? time[0] : parseInt(time[0]) + 12;

   return new Date(date[0], month, date[2], hour, 58, 30);
}

parseDate("2016-12-16 07:58:30 AM");
```